# how to export data from matlab to open modelica

Tags: matlab, openmodelica, simscape

I have a simscape model and a similar model in open modelica. I need to compare the results from both these models i.e. plot the results of the two models on the same plot/graph and compare the results. I would like to know how can I do this?  How can I export my simscape results to open modelica and plot them on the same graph.

Is there any command that will help me read matlab files which contains the results of my simscape model and plot them in open modelica?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: From MATLAB **to** Open Modelica, I wouldn't know. However, if you manage to export **from** Open Modelica and Simscape to any standard format (TXT, CSV, even binaries or HDF5), MATLAB will be able to read the data, which you can then plot in the same graph.

Comment: Thank you for answer. 
Sorry about changing the question again, I did figure out how to export from Open Modelica to MATLAB. 
But unfortunately I need to the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

OpenModelica can understand results files containing time series in two formats:

1. [Comma-separated values (CSV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), so something like

   ```
   time,var1,var2
   0,1,2.0
   0.1,2,3.0
   0.2,3,4.0
   0.3,4,5.0
   ```
2. Matlab MATv4 files, see the [OpenModelica User's Guide](https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/technical_details.html#the-matv4-result-file-format) for implementation details.

Open a result file in OMEdit: `File`->`Open Result File(s)` and navigate to your `.csv` or `.mat` file.

If Simscape can't output result files in the MATv4 format try CSV files.
If that isn't an output option for Simscape there are plenty of tools available to convert MAT/HDF5 to CSV files, e.g. Pandas in Python.